# I want to change Number format to date time format in cognos report studio in my query expression

Tags: cognos-10

In report studio, I am query expression  where I want to change integer value coming directly from DB as 20151231 as one row of the date column.

I want to change this column values in report studio as 31/12/2015 12:23:41 PM. I have used data format property also but it is not working. I need query for this.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways of doing this, but it's often easiest to do it on the database. If that's not an option, here's one approach.

Assuming your integer value query item is called 'IntDate':

- Create a data item called 'IntDateString' as follows:

  cast([IntDate], char(8))
- Create a second data item (call it whatever you want) as follows:

  cast( substring([IntDateString], 1, 4) || '-' || substring([IntDateString], 5, 2) || '-' || substring([IntDateString], 7, 2) , date )

You can now use and format this last query item as a date field however you wish.